# Convert language specific letters

Tags: r, vba

I was wondering if there is a way to convert language specific letters while importing a data frame.

I mean special characters like : ș ă î â to be converted to s a i a.

For now what i am doing is performing a manual replace all within excell before preparing the data for R. I found a VBA code to do bulk replacements of chars or strings, however in the VBA editor when I type in the special characters I get question marks.

I need this for a geocoding project.

Comment: Partial solution:  `chartr('șăîâ', "saia", TestString )`  but at least for me the R console does not handle the first two characters.

Comment: Can you read the file in UTF-8 and then replace not the letter itself but its UTF-8 code (http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The range of char codes 192..609 contains total 221 char that are representable in ASCII (i. e. can be converted from diacritic chars):

> À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý ÿ Ā ā Ă ă Ą ą Ć ć Ĉ ĉ Ċ ċ Č č Ď ď Đ đ Ē ē Ĕ ĕ Ė ė Ę ę Ě ě Ĝ ĝ Ğ ğ Ġ ġ Ģ ģ Ĥ ĥ Ħ ħ Ĩ ĩ Ī ī Ĭ ĭ Į į İ ı Ĵ ĵ Ķ ķ Ĺ ĺ Ļ ļ Ľ ľ Ł ł Ń ń Ņ ņ Ň ň Ō ō Ŏ ŏ Ő ő Œ œ Ŕ ŕ Ŗ ŗ Ř ř Ś ś Ŝ ŝ Ş ş Š š Ţ ţ Ť ť Ŧ ŧ Ũ ũ Ū ū Ŭ ŭ Ů ů Ű ű Ų ų Ŵ ŵ Ŷ ŷ Ÿ Ź ź Ż ż Ž ž ƀ Ɖ Ƒ ƒ Ɨ ƚ Ɵ Ơ ơ ƫ Ʈ Ư ư ƶ Ǎ ǎ Ǐ ǐ Ǒ ǒ Ǔ ǔ Ǖ ǖ Ǘ ǘ Ǚ ǚ Ǜ ǜ Ǟ ǟ Ǥ ǥ Ǧ ǧ Ǩ ǩ Ǫ ǫ Ǭ ǭ ǰ ɡ

Generally you can go without auxiliary worksheet, populating a dictionary with replaceable chars on the fly, something like the below code:

```vb
Sub Test()

    ReplaceDiacritics Selection

End Sub

Sub ReplaceDiacritics(oTargetRange As Range)

    Static oDiaChars As Object
    Dim i, j, sRange, sCured, sChar, aRes

    If oDiaChars Is Nothing Then
        Set oDiaChars = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        sRange = ""
        For i = 192 To 609
            sRange = sRange & ChrW(i)
        Next
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Type = 2
            .Mode = 3
            .Open
            .Charset = "ascii"
            .WriteText sRange
            .Position = 0
            sCured = .ReadText
            .Close
        End With
        For i = 192 To 609
            sChar = Mid(sCured, i - 191, 1)
            If sChar <> "?" Then oDiaChars(ChrW(i)) = sChar
        Next
    End If

    If oTargetRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        sRange = oTargetRange.Value
        For Each sChar In oDiaChars
            sRange = Replace(sRange, sChar, oDiaChars(sChar))
        Next
        oTargetRange.Value = sRange
    Else
        aRes = oTargetRange.Value
        For i = LBound(aRes, 1) To UBound(aRes, 1) ' rows
            For j = LBound(aRes, 2) To UBound(aRes, 2) ' columns
                For Each sChar In oDiaChars
                    aRes(i, j) = Replace(aRes(i, j), sChar, oDiaChars(sChar))
                Next
            Next
        Next
        oTargetRange.Value = aRes
    End If

End Sub
```

The dictionary declared as static thus it is populated at first run only, I tested the code with selection of 1000 cells 3500 chars length each, it takes about 8 secs for me. So to avoid hanging for a long time better to call it like `ReplaceDiacritics ActiveSheet.UsedRange`, but not `ReplaceDiacritics Cells`.

Answer (score 0):

After help from the community @cyboashu I am using this cheap, but rather effective VBA macro:

```
Sub replace()
'
Dim i As Integer
'selecting the sheet in which to do the replacements 
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
For i = 2 To 5

    Cells.Replace What:=Sheet2.Cells(i, 1), Replacement:=Sheet2.Cells(i, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

For this to work I had to create a new sheet and add it to the original excel. In my case it is called Sheet2 and I reference to it in the for loop, it can be expanded to a larger number of characters.

[image: Sheet2 structure]

If anyone can share more advance or optimal methods please do so and I will be gladly explore them!

Comment: You can use special characters in Excel's editor with `StrConv("à", vbFromUnicode)`

Answer (score 0):

In R (as your question is also tagged with R) you can use `iconv` with translitteration (however for me the first character doesn't show, it could depend on your OS) :

```r
> iconv("ș ă î â", "UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "? a i a"
```